# Tab bar icon not fit and when i select the icon it hide

Tags: ios, ios10

I am using tab bar in my project. The tab bar image not fit(see the below image1), and also i had another problem when i click the Tab bar it hide tab bar name or tab bar (See the below image 2).

My iphone version is 10.2.1 and ipad also have same issue

how to i resolve those issues. Please help me to find the write way to display the Image and name.  [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhbOf.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyTF9.png)

Comment: take image pixel 20*20 add to tab bar Try it.

Answer (score 0):

To change tint Color of you Tab bar use the code below.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

let me know weather it helps or not.